# How to get required combinations from different rows of column in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the different required combinations out from dataframe column with few rows.It is something like below:
I have following values in one of the columns of my df

```
Oy
On
G1
G2
A1
A2
A3
A4
R1
R2
R3
L1
L2
A5
A6
```

Here oy,on belong to group 1,

```
G1,g2 - group 2,
A1 to a4 - group 3,
R1 to r3 - group 4,
L1,l2 - group 5,
A5,a6 - group 6
```

Now I am trying all the combinations from each value of the each group ranging from 1 value to all like below:

```
Oy
Oy g1
Oy g1 a1
Oy g1 a1 r1
Oy g1 a1 r1 l1 
Oy g1 a1 r1 l1 a5
```

This will be for all possible combinations.note that within group combination is not desirable like g1 and g2 cannot come in same combination.

I know that this is possible with for loops with some if conditions.But looking for more efficient and elegant solution.

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to `itertools.product` on the various groupings. 
To get the groups you could do

```
first_letter = df[col].str[0].str.lower()
groups = df[col].groupby(first_letter).unique()
```

(`col` here is the name of the column describe above).

This gives a mapping from the first letter (lowercase) to an array of the unique values starting with that letter (lower or upper case). Then you can do `itertools.product(*groups)` to get all six-tuples containing one member from each group. 
To get all combinations of, say, the g and o groups, you can do `itertools.product(*groups[['g', 'o']])`

Comment: Joe,I am not clear on how are you handling groups above.As per what I said ,I have 6 groups here and I need all possible combinations...could you please elaborate considering all 6 groups...

Comment: I meant "six-tuples", not "five-tuples". Have you tried the code?

Comment: Got it Joe.Thanks